# ESLint CLI not picking up all errors that VSCode plugin is highlighting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I've been using eslint in VSCode and also have the plugin installed, but want to be able to lint a whole project as I added it part way into coding and want to check for errors without opening up every single file.

It's a single-root Workspace to keep the projects I'm currently working on together, but the root has folders for each project (Projects > [Project Name] > [Sub Project]). I'm only wanting to run the linter on one of the Projects at the moment, and that project is the only one with an `.eslintrc.json` file.

Opening individual files, the plugins flags the errors in the problem panel - one file I'm working on has 9 errors alone, however when running the CLI with *either* `eslint .` in the project directory, *or* `./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js .` brings up a total of 6 problems across the whole project. I have eslint installed both locally *and* globally, and I've tried uninstalling the global version to see if there was a conflict, but again I get the same output.

I've tried using the -c argument to ensure it's picking up the `.eslintrc.json` file, as well as forcing the local version to run (which doesn't make a difference to the output). Each time the output is the same (`6 Problems (4 errors, 2 warnings)`) but I *know* from opening single files that there are more.

Is there something obvious I'm missing to ensure that the CLI and the Plugin display the same errors when running in this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself.
When running the plugin, it lints all files that you open, however `eslint` by default only lints `*.js` files. I noticed that it seemed to be missing `.jsx` files from the report, and, as this was is a React project I added:

```
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["*.jsx"]
    }
]
```

to my `.eslintrc.json` file and all of the errors showed up when running `eslint .`

Comment: Btw, if you're using typescript, don't forget to do "*.tsx"!